# How to remove auto-formatting from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to know how to turn off `Android Studio`'s auto-formatting?

For some reason blank lines are always devoid of tabs or spaces, regardless of the scope or what so ever. Even if I manually place tabs in there, in a few moments they are gone. Its so annoying I always have to always press tab before writing code. It may be possible that this could be happing because I am using an older version of the program. But I am even unable to upgrade (a problem for another day, not today). So if anyone has a solution to this please share? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off most of the meddling with your text formatting in the menu...

Settings->Editor->General->Smart Keys

...and then untick as many things as possible.

I have not found a simple 'Just leave what I type alone' option.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the formatting style under `File>Settings>Editor>Code Style>Languages`.

`Edit:`

[image]Click on the Language you want to change the formatting.
You can see the the different tab to to change the spaces and lines.

`Note:`screen shot taken on Android Studio 1.4

Comment: I did find the options for the styling yes, but no option to turn it off or anything related to the specific problem I was having.

Comment: @user3892644 Which version of Android Studio do you have? For me, Under "Java" there is a tab "Tabs and Indents" with an option "Keep indents on empty lines", switched off by default. (Android Studio 1.4).

Comment: When I reopen this dialog `tab size` went back to 1